# cakePHP : get current user and current video

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a Commentscontroller. In this CommentsController I have an add action for adding comments to a video. When adding a comment, I need to select the user who is placing the comment and I need to select the video that gets the comment. See this as my backoffice.

I have a VideosController and what I want to do in the view action is loading the add action of the CommentsController. A comment is created by a user and a video has a comment. Also in this view I have the select fields, I need to select a user and video.

Now I want to retrieve the current logged in user and the current video.

Comment model :

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Video' => array(
        'className' => 'Video',
        'foreignKey' => 'video_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Video model :

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'className' => 'Comment',
        'foreignKey' => 'video_id',
        'dependent' => false,
    ),
);
```

add action CommentsController :

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Comment->create();
        if ($this->Comment->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The comment has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The comment could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $users = $this->Comment->User->find('list');
    $videos = $this->Comment->Video->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('users', 'videos'));
}
```

view action of VideosController:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    //Loading comment model
    $this->loadModel('Comment');

    //Using frontoffice layout
    $this->layout = 'default_front';

    //Getting the view of the video
    if (!$this->Video->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid video'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Video.' . $this->Video->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->set('video', $this->Video->find('first', $options));

    //Getting the timeline off the viewed video
    $tab = array('Video.Timeline' . $this->Video->Timeline->primaryKey => $id);
    //Getting the items of the Timeline
    $items = $this->Video->Timeline->Item->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Item.timeline_id' => $tab),'recursive'=>2));
    $this->set('items', $items);

    //Create comments
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Comment->create();
        if ($this->Comment->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The comment has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The comment could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    //Here I want the currently logged in user
    $users = $this->Comment->User->find('list');
    //Here I want the current video
    $videos = $this->Comment->Video->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('users', 'videos'));
}
```

view.ctp of videos

```
<fieldset>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('comment_body', array(
            'label' => '',
            'placeholder' => 'Share your thoughts',
        ));
        echo $this->Form->input('comment_created', array(
            'label' => 'Created',
            //'type' => 'hidden'
        ));
        echo $this->Form->input('user_id', array(
            //'type' => 'hidden'
        ));
        echo $this->Form->input('video_id', array(
            //'type' => 'hidden'
        ));
    ?>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always use,

```
$this->Auth->user('id');
```

In controller for accessing logged user's id .

While the $id is the id of video so your problem seems solved.

Comment: i didn't down-voted (actually i cannot down-vote) and i did provide you correct solution for your query